# Octave: std on sparse matrix too memory intensive

Tags: memory, octave, sparse-matrix, variance

I have a very large sparse matrix in Octave and I want to get the variance of each row. If I use
`std(A,1);`
it crashes because memory is exhausted.
Why is this?
The variance should be very easy to calculate for a sparse matrix, shouldn't it?
How can I make this work?

Comment: Yes, the algorithm for computing variances on a sparse matrix can be quite simple (depending on the format), but it does have to be implemented.

Comment: How can it be implemented efficiently? Is there a way to cycle through the entries of the sparse matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the standard deviation of just the nonzero entries in each column, then you can do:

```
[nrows, ncols] = size(A);

counts = sum(spones(A),1);

means = sum(A,1) ./ max(counts, 1);
[i,j,v] = find(A);
v = means(j);
placedmeans = sparse(i,j,v,nrows,ncols);

vars = sum((A - placedmeans).^2, 1) ./ max(counts, 1);

stds = sqrt(vars);
```

I can't imagine a situation where you would want to take the standard deviations of all the terms in each column of a sparse matrix (including zeros), but if so, you only need to count the number of zeros in each column and include them in the calculations:

```
[nrows,ncols] = size(A);

zerocounts = nrows - sum(spones(A),1);

means = sum(A,1) ./ nrows;
[i,j,v] = find(A);
v = means(j);
placedmeans = sparse(i,j,v,nrows,ncols);

vars = (sum((A - placedmeans).^2, 1) + zerocounts .* means.^2) ./ nrows;

stds = sqrt(vars);
```

Also, I don't know if you want to subtract one from the denominator of vars (counts and nrows respectively).

EDIT: corrected a bug which reconstructs the placedmeans matrix of the wrong size whenever A ends in a row or column of all zeros.  Also, the first case now returns a mean/var/std of zero whenever a column is all zeros (whereas before it would have been NaN)

Comment: This almost works, but there seems to be a bug. I need the second version, which also counts zeros. Unfortunately, it doesn't work if the matrix contains an entire row full of zeros at the end. It gives an exception about dimensions in that case. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Ok, that was a stupid comment. You can't take the variance of a row full of zeros. Do you know how I could alter the above code so that those that have no entries get 0 as variance?

Comment: You can absolutely take the variance of a row full of zeros.  It is zero.  (You can't, however, take the variance of an empty list, so I changed the first version to give 0 in that case).  However, the code I provided takes the standard deviation of each column (as would std(A,1)), not of each row.  Also, I've made an edit to fix the bug you mentioned.  It should work with any (nonempty) matrix now

Comment: I seem to be getting dumber by the minute. I am too overworked :-(